# jQuery submit a big form in parts

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a big form that is spliced in 4 divs, each div represent a step , everything is enclose in just 1 form, my problem is the form is becoming too big, because has the ability to add new fields , (pictures, text, languages) dynamically ,

so i was wondering if is there any option to submit this form in parts , my server has the limit of 20 fields per post, and i can not change this setting

Comment: Is it possible for you to send it as JSON input to server?

Comment: @Murali yes this will be the best solution, serialize your form on jSon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server limit bothers you you can Serialize the form in jSON and pass this as a single Parameter

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

like

```
var data = $("form#myform").serializeObject();
window.location = "url?data="+encodeURIComponent(data);
```

than on server

```
$data = json_decode($_GET["data"]);
foreach($data as $row)
{
 //Do What ever you want with $row
}
```

Or if you need to use $_POST

```
var post_data = { data : data};
$.post('url', post_data ,function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always pack the field values into a big json array, encode it and post it with jQuery.ajax. It will look like a big single field. On the server side, you can decode it and voila, limit bypassed. But honestly, what kind of server is that? I have never heard this kind of limitation before.

Another solution is to replicate the state of the form on the server side (for example, in a session storage), and make ajax calls to update individual fields in the session store. E.g. when the user leaves a field, you post the value of that single field to the server, and then the server updates the field value in the session store.

There can be many other possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create multiple forms, associated to each step you have ?

Comment: because i just want to click one button and submit everything, mutiples forms , means multiples submit button, although is posible to make a button and submit each one with jquery

Comment: You can json_encode all your forms field, so you only get one data posted : $('#your_form_id').serialize()

Answer (score 0):

@Cody answer works pretty good , but i had problem with file input,

This library http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ , works great too, and i was able to submit files, and support inner arrays, without any change